# Convert Swagger to C# object

Tags: c#, json

Is there an easy way to convert Json string to C# object?

I have a swagger file in json format and need to make it to C# object

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "Profiles",
    "title": "Profiles"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/api/Profiles/Get": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [ "Profiles"],
        "operationId": "Profiles_GetById",
        "consumes": [],
        "produces": [],
        "parameters": [{ "name": "id"}]
      }
    },
    "/api/Profiles": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Profiles"
        ],
        "operationId": "Profiles_GetBySubscriptionid",
        "consumes": [],
        "produces": [],
        "parameters": [{ "name": "subscriptionId"}]
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {}
}
```

So the problem that I am facing right now is that I have no idea how to convert paths to properties of my C# object. Specifically, I have no clue how I define a C# object properties for "/api/Profiles/Get", or "/api/Profiles".

```
public class SwaggerObject
{
  [JsonProperty("paths")]
  public SwaggerPath Paths { get; set;}
}
public class SwaggerPath {
  ... 
}
```

Comment: If you have a valid Json string I've used a Json converter to create a c# object. Example: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourModel>(Json);

Comment: There is a builtin tool in Visual Studio to generate classes based on json file. Just copy the json and somewhere in 'View' you will find 'paste json as classes'. If you want to do this manually you can try using JsonProperty with 'api....' but not sure if it's gonna work. The other way is to deserialize it to Dictionary<string,string>

Comment: @Mickers In my Parser class, I already used JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SwaggerObject>(json). The problem is Json format is name-value pair; hence  that I don't know how I should define the properties in the SwaggerPath so that it can contain "/api/Profiles/Get" or "/api/Profiles".

Comment: @MistyK  , the internal visual studio tool is in Edit rather than in View. 
This is actually very useful and lovely. I had to go to websites every single time.

Comment: If you want to convert swagger.json to object, microsoft.openapi.reader will be helpful

Answer (score 8):

If you have a valid swagger definition, you can use [AutoRest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest) to generate a client for you. The auto-generated client includes models for all of the types you define in your swagger document.

You can then call `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(json​)` after you retrieve the response. Better yet, you can you the auto generated client to make the HTTP calls in your .NET code.